# Is attribute-based encryption safe for production use?

Tags: encryption, audit

I'm very interested in attribute-based encryption (ABE). I see various working examples online, and I want to know, has it been verified as production-ready? What does it mean to have a security audit, and how do I know if ABE is safe for use with real customer data?

The use case I have in mind is for powering role-based access control (RBAC) within a general-purpose framework for building apps. Example: David has built a cool diagramming and visualization app using a framework which implements RBAC using ABE, and he's deployed it to the cloud. Now Bob has used David's app to make a cool diagram, and he wants to give Alice read and write access to this document. He also wants to share it with Chelsea, but he wants her to have read-only access.

Comment: What do you define as "verified as production-ready"? Verified by whom, and for what context? For your personal website? For a 3-man company? For a hospital? Without knowing anything about your scope or your requirements, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Fair enough. I've updated the question with requirements.

Comment: Why do you need ABE to implement RBAC?  RBAC is simple enough to implement on its own - I don't understand what ABE adds to the standard methods

Comment: The advantage is that the client app can dictate the policy without special logic built into the server-side application.

Comment: Aside from the above point, there's also a strong argument that an ABE-based approach would be inherently better than infrastructure-based approaches. https://medium.com/asecuritysite-when-bob-met-alice/towards-true-security-attribute-based-encryption-20d5799aeda6